# Detect number of bytes required for an arbitrary number in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to figure out the simplest way to write a function to detect the amount of bytes required for a number in Scala.

For instance the number

```
 0 should be 0 bytes
 1 should be 1 byte
 127 should be 1 byte
 128 should be 2 bytes
 32767 should be 2 bytes
 32768 should be 3 bytes
8388607 should be 3 bytes
8388608 should be 4 bytes
2147483647 should be 4 bytes
2147483648 should be 5 bytes
549755813887 should be 5 bytes
549755813888 should be 6 bytes
9223372036854775807 should be 8 bytes.
-1 should be 1 byte
-127 should be 1 bytes
-128 should be 2 bytes
-32767 should be 2 bytes
-32768 should be 3 bytes
-8388607 should be 3 bytes
-8388608 should be 4 bytes
-2147483647 should be 4 bytes
-2147483648 should be 5 bytes
-549755813887 should be 5 bytes
-549755813888 should be 6 bytes
-9223372036854775807 should be 8 bytes
```

is there any way to do this besides doing the math figuring out where the number is wrt 2^N?

Comment: hm. doesn't really make sense for negative numbers. E.g. for number -1, you would always take up as many digits as possible, because it's always `11111111` (all ones) regardless of the number of digits available. Otherwise it's just log2(n)/8.

Comment: Doesn't that still equal 1 byte? So if there was an `Int` allocated it would take up 32 bits of `1111...11`?

Comment: @Zoltán depends on how you represent (serialize?) it. But at least you need one bit more then for negative numbers. So it may takes one more byute for negativ numbers.

Comment: @Zoltán and 1 will take as many digits as possible (`00001` -- all zeroes and one 1). The question is, what is minimal amount (probably, alligned to 8).

Comment: Assuming you're only going as far as Long (so 8 bytes) you can do it in four comparisons: a comparison to check it if is negative, then three comparisons (binary-chop-compare to the largest number that will fit in length 1...8) . Equivalently, you can shift it 8 bits at a time until it becomes zero.

Comment: I'm not sure how `0` would fit in 0 bytes? Btw, -128 usually fits into 1 Byte as well

Comment: @Bergi I think the number system I am trying to represent is one's complement.

Comment: What do you do about `Long.MinValue`, then? It's -9223372036854775808. Should it be 9 bytes?

Comment: @sjrd I'm not sure. These are test cases that are written for the bitcoin protocol which stops at -9223372036854775807

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all the precisions in the comments, I guess the algorithm for negative numbers would be: whatever the answer for their opposite would be; and `Long.MinValue` is not an acceptable input value.

Therefore, I suggest:

```
def bytes(x: Long): Int = {
  val posx = x.abs
  if (posx == 0L) 0
  else (64 - java.lang.Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(posx)) / 8 + 1
}
```

Tests needed.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, you're basically asking for "what's the smallest power-of-2-number larger than my number", with a bit of adjustment for the extra digit for the sign (positive or negative).

Here's my solution, although the result differs for 0 and -128, because, as Bergi commented on your question, you can't really write 0 with 0 bytes, and -128 fits in 1 byte.

```
import Math._

def bytes(x: Double): Int = {
  val y = if (x >= 0) x + 1 else -x
  ceil((log(y)/log(2) + 1)/8).toInt
}
```